# What coordinates: 6 digits, 8 decimals and how to convert to Lat & Lng

Tags: coordinate-system, coordinates

I have found a public GeoJSON dataset that uses coordinates I can't identify.
The first tuple is:

[146476.39635656,165501.27742543]

This tuple is located in Brussels, Belgium (UTM 31) and is close to [4.35659887, 50.83598669].

- What format is it?
- What is the latitude & longitude of the example above?

Comment: There should be crs definition in the geojson file like this: "crs": { "type": "name", "properties": { "name": "urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::23700" } }

Comment: Thanks, it's EPSG:31370, the Belgian Lambert 72 system. I found out how to convert to Lat &Lng. I guess I can delete the question.

Comment: You can delete your question or you can ask @Zoltan to publish his suggestion as answer and then accept it, so that it can help somebody else with similar problem.

Comment: @Zoltan Please publish your comment as answer. You can also elaborate on how to convert from 1 standard to another one. This is what I immediately did after having identified the standard..

Comment: @roland done. I've added an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There should be crs definition in the geojson file like this:

```
"crs": { "type": "name", "properties": { "name": "urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::23700" } }
```